# Remove duplicate date excluding first and last in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to remove the all duplicate date excluding 1st and last date.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

I would like to do the B column like D column.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: First and last date in the date-range? Or in the spreadsheet (A1:Z10)? Also, please dont provide links as examples - try your best to replicated the idea in your post.

Comment: In (B2:B30) Range

Answer (score 1):

## CHOOSE, ROW, MIN, MAX, DAY

If your Source Range is `B2:B30` and your resulting data starts in `D2`, use the following **array formula** (in `D2`):

```
=CHOOSE(MOD((ROW()-ROW(D$2)),3)+1,IF(MIN(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))=0,"",MIN(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))),IF(MAX(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))=0,"",MAX(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))),"")
```

---

To input a formula as an array formula, you have to copy the formula to the formula bar and hold **LEFT CTRL SHIFT** and press **ENTER**.

The resulting formula will contain braces {} i.e. will look like this:

```
{=CHOOSE(MOD((ROW()-ROW(D$2)),3)+1,IF(MIN(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))=0,"",MIN(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))),IF(MAX(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))=0,"",MAX(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))),"")}
```

---

### History

The formula is a combination of several formulas.

**Array Formulas**

```
=MIN(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))
=MAX(IF(DAY($B$2:$B$30)=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1,$B$2:$B$30))
```

**Normal Formulas**

```
=INT((ROW()-ROW(D$2))/3)+1
=MOD((ROW()-ROW(D$2)),3)+1
```

**And finally the CHOOSE formula**

```
=CHOOSE(MOD((ROW()-ROW(D$2)),3)+1,1,2,3)
```

where instead of 1, 2 and 3 the various conditions are placed instead:

**MIN**, **MAX** and **""**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation (not explicitly array formula)

```
=IFERROR(
CHOOSE(MOD(ROWS($1:3),3)+1,
AGGREGATE(15,6,B$2:B$30/(INT(B$2:B$30)=AGGREGATE(15,6,INT(B$2:B$30)/(INT(B$2:B$30)>D1),1)),1),
AGGREGATE(14,6,B$2:B$30/(INT(B$2:B$30)=AGGREGATE(15,6,INT(B$2:B$30)/(INT(B$2:B$30)>D1),1)),1),
""),
"")
```

but because I am comparing the dates with the date 3 rows earlier (initially in D1) the formula has to be entered in D4 and D1 and D2 have to be left blank.

[image]